# Prevent visual studio from appending folder name to new classes?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How can I prevent Visual Studio from naming the classes for new pages that are in folders from being named with the folder name? Does this method not set "right" with anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Naming classes or assigning classes to namespaces?

Visual Studio is assuming your project has a namespace hierarchy that mimics the folder structure in your project.  I'm not sure if there is a way to override this behavior; when it bothers me I just create new classes on the root folder of my project and then move them to the folder I want.

Comment: No. It appends the Folder Name to the class. I know of the namespace thing too. This is different.